# Regular Expression for alphabet it may contain numbers but should not contain all numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Need validation form `name` Some valid values are `abc` or `ABc123` or `123Xyb`.

bellow are invalid values `34324234` or `_jdf434` etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, give clear indications to what is valid and what is not, the examples stated are not sufficiently explanatory.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. Is this about JavaScript, or Ruby? (It's not about Ruby-on-Rails.)

Comment: Only alpha numeric, but numeric is optional and atlease one alphabet is required

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need validation for both javascript and Ruby

Comment: Put that in the question, and answer Pramod's question: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What has your research turned up?

Comment: I have used /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value), but this validates only letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (expressed in JavaScript):

```js
/^[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i
```

That says there can be zero or more alphanumeric characters followed by a single alphabetic character followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters.

Example:

```js
var tests = [
  {valid: true, value: "abc"},
  {valid: true, value: "ABc123"},
  {valid: true, value: "123Xyb"},
  {valid: false, value: "34324234"},
  {valid: false, value: "_jdf434"}
];
var rex = /^[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i;
tests.forEach(function(test) {
  var valid = rex.test(test.value);
  console.log(test.value, valid, !valid == !test.valid ? "Pass" : "Fail");
});
```

Comment: Hi @crowder thank you for your answer, can you please make changes to allow space. i.e. want to make "abc xyx" also valid

Comment: @Santi: Due respect, I think you need to read up on regular expressions and make that change yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp.test` function:

```
function validateName(name) {
    return !/^[0-9]+$|[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(name);
}

console.log(validateName("ABc123"));   // true
console.log(validateName("123Xyb"));   // true
console.log(validateName("ABc123"));   // true
console.log(validateName("34324234")); // false
console.log(validateName("_jdf434"));  // false
console.log(validateName("df/434"));   // false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score -1):

```
[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*
```

You can use this regular expression.

Comment: *"Some valid values are `abc` or `ABc123` or `123Xyb`"*